# warning Multiple directives found

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

i use subsonic 3. when i compiled the ORM, i get errors.
i have the following warning too and i am connecting to mysql database

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Common" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
```

Warning 9   Multiple template directives were found in the template. All but the first one will be ignored. Multiple parameters to the template directive should be specified within one template directive.    D:\TradingTools\CODE\ConsoleApplication8\subsoniccomponents\Settings.ttinclude  1   4   backtester

the errors i get are

```
Error   5   ; expected  D:\TradingTools\CODE\ConsoleApplication8\subsoniccomponents\ActiveRecord.cs 1800    17  backtester
```

the autogenerated code looks like following

```
decimal? _sum(revenueinCDn);
        public decimal? sum(revenueinCDn)
        {
            get { return _sum(revenueinCDn); }
            set
            {
                if(_sum(revenueinCDn)!=value){
                    _sum(revenueinCDn)=value;
                    var col=tbl.Columns.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="sum(revenueinCDn)");
                    if(col!=null){
                        if(!_dirtyColumns.Any(x=>x.Name==col.Name) && _isLoaded){
                            _dirtyColumns.Add(col);
                        }
                    }
                    OnChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

there are too many errors in this auto generated code.
how can i fix it?

Comment: What TT template are you using / can you post up the actual file?

Comment: i really could not upload file here so i uploaded to code viewer 
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29a9  context.tt 
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29aa  mysql.ttinclude
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29ab  settings.tt
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29ac  storedprocedures.tt
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29ad  structs.tt